# is there any thing like XAMPP but for tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, xampp

i am looking to start doing some web development with tomcat. is there any good easy bundle for MySql db and tomcat server? something like XAMPP just for java to save all the hassle of the configurations?

in case not can someone direct me to a nice tutorial on how to do so?

thanks :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any thing like XAMPP but for tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578209/is-there-any-thing-like-xampp-but-for-tomcat) (I'm voting to close this one, because there is a more obvious answer to the other one)

Comment: @Sean: Better to delete your answer there and post it here. The duplicate is being closed in five...four...three...two...

Answer (score 1):

Since the other question was closed I am reposting-this answer here:

XAMPP has a Tomcat add-on. You just need to download and install that.

Here's the link to [the windows version](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#644)