# Package an application including java war file, Tomcat, DB

Tags: java, installation, executable

i have a java based web application, i have the source code as well as the war file, the application uses mySql and need some web server like tomcat all to be added to some package that can be directly installed on `window` and `linux` machines directly..

i need to setup DB, WebServer, and app in one go. Would be great if it can create services for all as well.

is it possible???

i mean the user should just give the location to store and everything should get stored in one go, is it feasible? and if yes please guide me how to do so...

Comment: For Linux you should provide suitable installation instructions inside the native package manager, i.e. "sudo apt-get foo bar fum" for Ubuntu etc.

Answer (score 5):

In short: Yes, it is.

Projects like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html) are already following that approach. All relevant software components are inside a single ZIP file which you can extract to an arbitrary location on the user's harddisk. All configuration then uses relative paths when referencing files.

So essentially, you will have to put in a little effort in advance to make the "installation" as easy as possible. Maybe you can simply build upon a project like XAMPP and use the infrastructure already provided?

Comment: I am using java this is for PHP :(

Comment: I was just suggesting to use it as a basis. You could strip out PHP and maybe Apache (if not required) and add a JDK + Tomcat installation instead. There are [threads here about this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578201/is-there-any-thing-like-xampp-but-for-tomcat).